# Check if a specific value occur multiple times in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on a simple KNN algorithm, where I want to add a if statement that resolves a tie (if there's an equal number of neighbors from several different classes around a test point). The problem occurs when I want to find if the maximum value of an array occurs more than once, but i can't seem to find a function that does this. What i want:

```
unique, counts = np.unique(k_nearest_labels, return_counts=True)

if (len(unique)>1) and (frequency of max(counts) in counts > 1)
    return the nearest of the tied points
```

Where `counts` is the frequency of the numbers in `unique`. How do I solve the second condition in the if statetent? Or is there a different solution I'm overlooking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I suggest that you edit your question removing the answer part and create a post below answering your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, forgot I could create a boolean array and take the sum, here's my solution for people who stumble upon this.

```
 if (len(unique)>1) and (frequency of max(counts) in counts > 1)
```

can be written as:

```
 if (len(unique)>1) and (np.sum(counts == np.max(counts)) > 1):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually skip the use of `np.unique` (which is fairly computationally expensive) and still get what you want:

```
maxcount = (k_nearest_labels == k_nearest_labels.max()).sum()
if k_nearest_labels.size > maxcount and maxcount > 1:
    ...do stuff...
```

Also: yaaay! You answered your own question while you were writing it. That's always fun. You should definitely take Hemerson's suggestion and split your edit with the answer into a proper answer (it'll make it easier to find for others).

Comment: I just tried this, but it doesn't apply unfortunately. I need the to know if the frequency of the labels in the k_nearest_labels array. The max value of this array will always be the class with highest label. So if i had a 7NN result for a single test point (sorted from closest to furthest): `7_nearest_labels = [1,1,1, 4, 2, 2, 2]`. Here class 1 and 2 is tied, but the max value is class 4. So here I would choose 1 as the predicted class, as it's closer than 2. But thanks for the answer!

Comment: @ØysteinSkogvold Ah. Your example makes it much clearer: you're trying to make a decision based on the modes of `k_nearest_labels `. In that case, `unique` is definitely the function you want to use. The only thing I'd add is that the first part of your conditional statement is redundant, since there's no condition in which `len(unique)>1` will be False when `np.sum(counts == np.max(counts)) > 1` is True.